# Angular CLI - 'Cannot find module' when using custom library created with 'ng new library'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to consume my own library after creating it with the Angular CLI using `ng new library lib-name`.

I'm trying to import the library as documented, this way:

```
import {MyLibModule} from 'ngx-mylib';
```

But I get the following error:

```
 error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-mylib'.
```

I did `ng build ngx-mylib` and also verified my tsconfig.json has the following paths (which are added automatically using the CLI):

```
"paths": {
      "ngx-mylib": [
        "dist/ngx-chartjs"
      ],
      "ngx-mylib/*": [
        "dist/ngx-chartjs/*"
      ]
    }
```

public-api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/charts.service';
export * from './lib/chart.component';
export * from './lib/charts.module';
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Show public_api_.ts of your library

Comment: Added the public_api file

Comment: Have you actually built the library so that it ends up in the dist folder? I've done this mistake too many times.

Comment: Hi i have the same problem, you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After build your library you have to pack it.

Go to your dist folder and run

```
npm pack
```

this will create a your-lib-name.tgz file and then you can use it on your projects.

Use it like this:

```
npm install path-to-your-tgz-file/your-lib.tgz
```

You can also publish it to npm or to a private repository.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to do this process every time I change something in the library?

Comment: Yes you need - try to use semantic versioning in your library.

Comment: No you don't need to use `npm pack` and then install it. I assume you have your main project in the same CLI project and is using a library as part of the `projects` folder within. Then you can simply consume it without involving `npm` at all.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz that's what I tried, but this question is on the error I get.

Comment: did the same but getting error "Cannot find module '@angular/core' ".

Comment: this explanation it's not for call library from local, but for publish on registry npm

Answer (score 0):

try to build it again and then run your project sometimes angular can't build the library properly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding MyLibModule to your app.module imports and exports.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Angular 14) I had to add the paths in the `tsconfig.app.json` too.

---

First check that your `tsconfig.json` contains the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "dist/my-lib"
      ],
      "my-lib/*": [
        "dist/my-lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This should be generated automatically when creating your lib (using `ng generate library my-lib`).

Now what I had to add is the following in `src/tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "../dist/my-lib"
      ],
      "my-lib/*": [
        "../dist/my-lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You should now be able to import your lib using `import { MyLibModule } from 'my-lib';`.