# Cannot find modules from local package

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library

I've create an Angular library **my-lib** project follow this [Angular.io tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries), after build success, I've run `npm pack` at `./projects/my-lib` path to  compress **my-lib** following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58111133) to pack it to **.tgz** package.

In **my-app** project, I've copied `my-lib-xxx.tgz` (packed from **my-lib** library) to root directory then run `npm install ./my-lib-xxx.tgz --save-dev`. After that, **my-app** `package.json` file look like this:

```
devDependencies: {
    ...
    "my-lib":"file:my-lib-xxx.tgz",
    ...
}
```

But when I import **my-lib** to my app.module.ts, IDE keep telling me that it **Cannot find module 'my-lib'. ts(2307)**.

Did I missing something?

p/s: I've generated **my-lib** library in the same workspace with **my-app** and it work. But I want to make those 2 separated from each other.

I'm using angular 8 with Visual Studio Code